# ruby regex finding first two numbers in a string

Tags: ruby, regex

If I have a string like

```
6d7411014f
```

I want to read the the occurrence of first two integers and put the final number in a variable

Based on above example my variable would contain `67`

more examples:

```
d550dfe10a
```

variable would be `55`

What i've tried is `\d` but that gives me 6. how do I get the second number?

Comment: You are searching for the first 2 digits not integers. If you would search for the first 2 integers your result would be 67411014.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really can't answer this exactly in Ruby, but a regex to do it is:

```
/^\D*(\d)\D*(\d)/
```

Then you have to concatenate `$1` and `$2` (or whatever they are called in Ruby).

Comment: With added ruby: `my_string.match(/^\D*(\d)\D*(\d)/).captures.join`. This will return the string representation of the two first digits in `my_string`.

Answer (score 7):

I'd use `scan` for this sort of thing:

```
n = my_string.scan(/\d/)[0,2].join.to_i
```

You'd have to decide what you want to do if there aren't two numbers though.

For example:

```
>> '6d7411014f'.scan(/\d/)[0,2].join.to_i
=> 67

>> 'd550dfe10a'.scan(/\d/)[0,2].join.to_i
=> 55

>> 'pancakes'.scan(/\d/)[0,2].join.to_i
=> 0

>> '6 pancakes'.scan(/\d/)[0,2].join.to_i
=> 6
```

References:

- [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan)
- [`Array#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D)
- [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join)

Answer (score 0):

Building off of sidyll's answer,

```
string = '6d7411014f'
matched_vals = string.match(/^\D*(\d)\D*(\d)/)
extracted_val = matched_vals[1].to_i * 10 + matched_vals[2].to_i
```